# Cannot Change ObservableCollection during an CollectionChanged Event TPL

Tags: .net, wpf, task-parallel-library, observablecollection

I am getting this error intermittently when I call .Clear() on the ObservableCollection in a button click handler. I am confused because I do have other TPL tasks running yet all update the ObservableCollection through:

```
mainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate()
{
 this.myCollection.Add(myItem);
}));
```

Does not the dispatcher in essense make my ObservableCollection thread safe because all operations would be atomic on the main UI thread? BTW: I am also updating some fields of the collection members in a DispatcherTimer but not removing or adding items to the collection in the timer.tick handler.

James:

I create a sample app to isolate the issue yet everything works fine the sample. So something else in my app must be tripping the collectionchanged on a different thread.
This all works fine, you can .Clear without error:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <Button Name="clear" Height="23" Click="clear_Click"></Button>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private DispatcherTimer myTimer = null;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        Loaded +=new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
    }

    private bool isLoaded = false;
    void  MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isLoaded) return;
        isLoaded = true;

        var task = new Task(() => AddObjectsTask());
        task.Start();


        myTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        myTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(myTimer_Tick);
        myTimer.Start();

        _MyCollection.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(_MyCollection_CollectionChanged);

    }

    void _MyCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            var query = (from n in _MyCollection select n).ToList();
            if (query.Any())
            {
                foreach (SomeObject o in query)
                {
                    o.Name = (Convert.ToInt64(o.Name) + 1).ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this._MyCollection.Add(new SomeObject() { Name = 99.ToString() }); 
    }

    void AddObjectsTask()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(true)
        {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate() 
        { 
            this._MyCollection.Add(new SomeObject() { Name = i.ToString() }); 
        })); 
            i++;
        }
    }


    private void clear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _MyCollection.Clear();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<SomeObject> _MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<SomeObject>();
    public ObservableCollection<SomeObject> MyCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _MyCollection;
        }
    }

}

public class SomeObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    private string _Name = string.Empty;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the other code that modifies the collection and the exception info.  Also, please add a tag for the UI framework (WPF?)

Comment: If you're modifying collection list members' properties in timer tick and those are data-bound to UI controls, some UI frameworks will throw if you're not marshaling it to the right thread

Comment: Seems that in my _CollectionChanged event handler that I was spinning off a 3rd party component that displayed a progress dialog. Once I turned that off that option to display progress, no more error. Not sure what was happening. If that was doing something to my mainwindow dispatcher?